# mod_rewrite subdomain and clen url in codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I suppose my domain is "www.domain.com"
and I have a file system

```
public_html
   |----ds
        |--application
            |--cache
            |--controller
                 ...

        |--css
        |--image
        |--system
        |--index.php
   |----zs
   |----fd
```

public_html is root directory.

I coding in .htacess with have condition this ::

1) ds Directory is subdomain. when URL is ds.domain.com. It mapping filepath in www.domain.com/ds/index.php/

2) I want to clean URL form www.domain.com/ds/index.php/translate/paintext (example full url) to ds.domain.com/translate/paintext (clean url)

**how to coding in .htacess ?**

/************************************************************************/

I put the .htacess in /ds folder and try to coding :

```
#subdomain to subdirectory
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com/ds/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://ds.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]    

#clean URL from codeigniter 
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|lib|css|image)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

**What is wrong??**

Answer (score 0):

At least one thing that is wrong is your `HTTP_HOST`. That variable is the **hostname**, and hostnames contain no URL path info in them. So `www.domain.com/ds/` will never exist as a hostname. Change it to:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ds/(.*)$ http://ds.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

The second issue looks fine. But if you want to *redirect* a request for `/index.php` to a new URL that doesn't have the "index.php" part, you need a new rule to do that:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+index\.php/
RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```